# npm start not working due to webpack issue

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

I  had installed expo globally to learn react-native seeing a tutorial.
Now when I'm trying to make a new react app and run npm start I'm getting the following message.

```
yarn start
yarn run v1.22.4
$ react-scripts start
 
There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.
It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.
 
The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:
 
  "webpack": "4.42.0"
 
Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of webpack was detected higher up in the tree:
 
  /home/nikunj/node_modules/webpack (version: 4.43.0) 
 
Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to-debug issues.
 
If you would prefer to ignore this check, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That will permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.
 
To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:
 
  1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
  2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
  3. Remove "webpack" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
  4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.
 
In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem.
If this has not helped, there are a few other things you can try:
 
  5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
     This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.
 
  6. Check if /home/nikunj/node_modules/webpack is outside your project directory.
     For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.
 
  7. Try running npm ls webpack in your project folder.
     This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed webpack.
 
If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That would permanently disable this preflight check in case you want to proceed anyway.
 
P.S. We know this message is long but please read the steps above :-) We hope you find them helpful!
 
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I tried several approaches to solve the problem.
Firstly i followed the first 4 steps in the error message but they did'nt work out as when i did

> npm ls webpack

it returned

```
/home/nikunj
└─┬ expo-cli@3.24.2
  └─┬ @expo/xdl@57.9.31
    ├─┬ @expo/webpack-config@0.12.25
    │ └── webpack@4.43.0  deduped
    └── webpack@4.43.0
```

Then I uninstalled expo-cli globally using

> yarn global remove expo-cli

but even if i do that it is still giving me the same tree for npm ls webpack.
I also tried doing npm rm home/nikunj/expo-cli@3.24.2  but that is not solving the problem as still i get the same tree on npm ls webpack

Comment: @AntoineRaoulIscaros yes i tried that it didn't work as the webpack is outside the directory it was installed globally when i installed expo cli globally

Comment: What about step 6? Is `/home/nikunj/node_modules` really the right place for you?

Comment: @madflow I don't know , i eventually had to delete nodejs and npm and delete all related folders and then reinstall it , as the globally installed expo was deleted in the process that solved my issue , I'm never going to install something globally using npm now ^_^